# NameValueCollection in c# sonarlint

Tags: c#

I use NameValueCollection for testing HttpHeader mock in c#, I use NUnit 3

I am getting an info in visual studio, 
[IDE0028](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0028): Collection initialization can be simplified

This is my current code

```
NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic aGVsbG86aGVsbG8=");
```

How to make this code

```
NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection()
{
   //add element here
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be same like we do for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` like:

```
NameValueCollection  headers = new NameValueCollection()
{
    {"Authorization", "Basic aGVsbG86aGVsbG8="},
    {"AnotherName"  , "Another Value"}
};
```